# Django all-access - ImportError

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on

I am trying to use the django-all-access application to write a SSO for Social Networks such as Facebook, Twitter, G+, etc... Found on: https://github.com/mlavin/django-all-access

I am trying to include it in my settings.py, see below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'my_app_s_name',
'allaccess',
)
```

However, when I try to run my application (python manage.py runserver), I get the following error:

**ImportError: No module named allaccess**

Any ideas where the issue is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it installed, i.e. `python -c 'import allaccess'`returns no errors? please provide complete trace.

Comment: Fair point, it didn't seem to be installed, I got the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named allaccess. I realized I didn't run the following command: pip install django-all-access as superuser, so it's now installed and doesn't return any error. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to `pip install django-all-access`